# Acer aspire laptop (Win7-64) forgets my settings

Tags: windows-7, laptop, acer-aspire

I've had a Windows-7 (64) Acer aspire laptop working fine for several years. Occasioanlly it gets used by house quests and people other than myself. Now today when I switch it on, it appears to have forgotten all of my settings, e.g. my background image, my taskbar location, my windows theme, my choice of icons to have on the desktop, and many other things. But all my files are still fine and the computer works, including the wifi connection. I then tried changing all of those things to how I like them, but after another reboot - it forgot them all over again.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I appear to be logged in a "mick-acer" - there do no a ppear to be any other logins. I.e. if I select switch user, my only choice is "mick-acer".

Comment: are you getting a message that you are signed in with a temporary account?

Comment: No. During the bootup sequence, there is no indication that anything has gone wrong. No "there appears to be a glitch.. repairing now" types of message. Just "everything ok, we're just starting this pc up" kind of stuff.

Comment: How many profile folders are there in C:\Users\?

Comment: There are three folders in c:\users, "mick-acer", "Public" and "TEMP".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much flailing, I found I had a corrupted user profile. Fix [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/upon-reboot-restart-windows-7-forgets-window-and/5dddac97-de12-4f4b-9237-fe1d3b714c39).